# How to Store Fetch API JSON Response in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch-api

I want to store a Fetch API JSON as a JavaScript object, so I can use it elsewhere. The console.log test works, but I can't access the data.

The Following Works: It shows console entries with three to-do items:

```
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/todos')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(success => console.log(success));
```

The Following Does Not Work:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/todos')
.then(data => data.json())
.then(success => JSON.parse(success));
```

If I try to access success, it does not contain any data.

Have tried console.log, which works.

Have also tried the following, which works:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/todos')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        let output = '';
        data.forEach(function (todo) {
        output += `
            <ul>
                <li>ID: ${todo.id}</li>
                <li>Title: ${todo.title}</li>
                <li>IsDone: ${todo.isdone}</li>
            </ul>
            `;
        });
        document.getElementById('ToDoList').innerHTML = output;
        return output;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Something went wrong: ', err));
```

However, I can't manually update inner HTML; I need the object to do other UX.

Comment: `success => JSON.parse(success)` <- the response has already been parsed as JSON via `data.json()`. You don't need to parse it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a function like below:

```
 function doSomething(success){
   //do whatever you like
 }

 fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/todos')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(success => doSomething(success));
```

Comment: If that helps you. Please choose my answer as the correct answer. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can just declare a variable outside and assign your result to it like this

```
var yourTodos;

fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/todos')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(success => yourTodos = success);
```

Then you have the `yourTodos` as your javascript object that you can use whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async await like below

```
async function consumingFunc () {
  let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/todos')
  console.log(response)
}

 consumingFunc()
```