# Where is the JSON stored in response variable?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Where is the JSON data stored in the fetch() response variable?

I tried examining the properties in the console by checking the headers but I don't see it there.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Store Fetch API JSON Response in a JavaScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643149/how-to-store-fetch-api-json-response-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @emix ya, i'll do that. in the meantime i don't see it in the body https://i.imgur.com/wMr9ZgI.png

Comment: @jjrabbit - `body` is a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream), to get the data from it you have to *read* it. It's not stored in a property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where is the JSON data stored in the fetch() response variable?

Initially, it isn't. When you get the response from `fetch`, the body of the response hasn't been read (by the `fetch` part of things) yet (it may well be waiting in some buffer in the browser's ajax module, but you can't access it directly). It's waiting for you to read it via the `text`, `json`, `arrayBuffer`, `blob`, or `formData`methods.

In your case, you're presumably using `json`. Once you call `json`, the body is read into an internal buffer and parsed, then the result of parsing it is used to fulfill the promise from the `json` method. So at that point, it's stored within the promise object `json` returned, accessible by consuming the promise (and not in any other way).

To access the JSON of a response, you call `json` and use the resulting promise:

```
fetch(/*...*/)
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status code " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // Use the parsed data here
})
.catch(error => {                    // If you return the chain, you can leave this off
    // Handle/report the error here
});
```

or within an `async` function:

```
const response = await fetch(/*...*/);
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP status code " + response.status);
}
const data = await response.json();
// Use the parsed data here
```

Answer (score 2):

when you call fetch service, you get a response in the response object

```
fetch('./api/myservice')
.then(
function(response) {
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
      response.status);
    return;
  }

  // response
  response.json().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
)
.catch(function(err) {
console.log('Fetch Error :', err);
});
```